# Octave jdk and ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, 15.04, jdk

i need to install I/O package so i need to install jdk and set the path java home as seen here

http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CGEQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenjevis.org%2Fattachments%2Fdownload%2F380%2FHow_to_install_the_java_package_in_Octave_20120924.pdf&ei=a5FhVbraIIeC7gaEyoDABw&usg=AFQjCNEUR6imMC68sWBexsRfn5poWOtw2A&sig2=tIpVKxtzCTTuxkkYNX_TPQ

but i am new so i am scared about potential unintended consequencies of that set of instructions.

Can anybody help me?

THX a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Instead of linking to the entire 3-page document, could you please let us know what instruction  exactly scares you?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the official packages from Ubuntu there not much wrong you can do. I would install the following packages using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-io octave-java openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre  openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

and then set the java path in `.octaverc`. Create the file using the  terminal

```
gedit $HOME/.octaverc
```

and paste inside

```
setenv ("JAVA_HOME", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64");
```